# Elasticsearch NoClassDefFoundError for PostingFormats

Tags: java, elasticsearch, maven-assembly-plugin

Get a NoClassDefFoundError when attempting to create an index using java with embedded elasticsearch.

- Versions Java 1.7 and Elasticsearch 1.3.2
- Building with maven assembly plugin
- Running using a jar that includes all dependencies

This is a snippet of stack trace:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class    org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.PostingFormats
at   org.elasticsearch.index.codec.CodecModule.configurePostingsFormats(CodecModule.java:126)
```

- This class is contained within the dependencies jar for elastic search
- Do not get this error when running with exploded classes on classpath rather than the jar.
- Have cleaned out all previous snapshots and classes etc. to avoid any lib clashes.

Is this something to do with the META-INF/services folder within the elastisearch.jar and requires use of maven-shade-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a number of files contained within the META-INF/services of various lucene and elasticsearch jars. Some of these files have the same filename, e.g.

```
org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat
```

The maven-shade-plugin solves this problem by combining the entries into one file. The actual exception is an IllegalArgEx, as

```
org.apache.lucene.codecs.memory.DirectPostingsFormat
```

cannot be loaded from some statically initialised collection